# What is the alternative to SVG fonts on website?

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts

I want to use a highly responsive logo text with a custom font. I realised that almost every browser is not supporting SVG fonts, which means that it's not an option: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fonts.

What options are there and what is the right way of solving the problem?

I could add an image with high resolution and scale it down? 
Just use Header-tag? But how could you scale it based on the width of the screen?
Is there a vector based option other than SVG?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @SaucedApples You find this question too subjective? As there are more than one solution that probably is best in different situations, I can't ask for the one and only right way of doing it. I still find my question pretty clear.

Comment: Pay more attention.  You first question is opinion based, which is why the link and flag to close.

Comment: Fonts are generally vector based these days even though they don't use SVG as their format.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yep. But is there a way to scale fonts in a percentage way? Like you can do with image using "%" or "vw"?

Comment: font-size="50%" or font-size="1vw"

Comment: @RobertLongson I want the text to be the same width as the image. https://jsfiddle.net/r72u5c8v/9/

Setting font-size:50vw; will obviously not work since font is based on it's height.

Comment: You'd have to do that with javascript. Get the length of the text at some font size and scale it.

Comment: @RobertLongson Alright. So the question is.. Is it better to do this kind of thing using an image instead? Isn't javascript the worst solution in the end?

Comment: Not enough information to answer that. I don't know what the logo looks like. And there's probably lots of different options even if I did know what the logo looked like.

Comment: @yeouuu Because it has a custom font, which is not supported by the browsers. SVG should only be used by images or with default fonts.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ye, won't show either font nor text. But it's simply a text. That's it. Nothing special about it :)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your logo is only letters doesn't mean that it **has** to be letters. In reality, they are just *shapes that resemble letters*.

Make an `svg` shape, or a large enough `.png` and you can scale it as you like.

People don't care if it is pure text, svg, png or jpg, they will read it anyways. And I believe nobody will try to select it or copy-paste it, and if you want it to be readable by screen readers, just add it's texts in the `alt` attribute.

Comment: But the problem in my case was custom font. Chrome does not longer support custom fonts in svg.

Comment: Then don't use one, make the logo in the program of your choice, convert it to paths and export it as an svg.

Comment: Oh ye.. Never thought of actually making the text as path instead of actual text. Not used to illustrator and .svg format. Thanks!